# How do I unlock all the characters?

Tags: mario-tennis-open

Who are the secret characters in Mario Tennis Open, and how do I unlock them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Unlockables:**
>
> - Baby Mario (Speed): (unlocked after Level 3 of Super Mario Tennis (1-3) is completed)
> - Baby Peach (Tricky): (unlocked after Level 3 of Ring Shot (Pro Rings) is completed)
> - Luma (Technique): (unlocked after Level 3 of Galaxy Rally (Superstar) is completed)
> - Dry Bowser (Defense): (unlocked after Level 3 of Ink Showdown (Inksplosion) is completed)

Check [the Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Tennis_Open#QR_Downloadable_Characters) out for more info on the characters of the game.

Comment: ah, dang. No Koopa! I guess I'll need to settle for Diddy Kong.

Answer (score 1):

Baby Mario:Complete 1-3 in Super Mario Tennis
Baby Peach:Complete Pro Rings in Ring Shot
Luma:Complete Superstar in Galaxy Rally
Dry Bowser:Complete Inksplosion in Ink Showdown
Yoshis red blue black pink light blue white and yellow:Have your 3DS scan the QR codes

Comment: I only have the Yoshis and Dry Bowser unlocked but im close to unlocking Luma and Baby Peach.

Comment: Read my anwser CAREFULLY!